# EF Core ends in infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created an API with .net core and EF Core (7.7). Now I created a many to many relationship mapping table by myself and configured the relationships correctly. Ive done this multiple times in my project and it works everywhere except here:

- 1 Machine has multiple SpareParts
- 1 SpareParts is contained by multiple Machines

So I defined this collection in `SparePart` and `Machine` entities:

```
    public virtual ICollection<MachineSparePart> MachineMappings { get; set; } = new List<MachineSparePart>();

    public ICollection<MachineSparePart> SparePartMappings { get; set; } = new List<MachineSparePart>();
```

This is the many-to-many mapping table:

```
    [Table("MachineSparePart", Schema = "Spare")]
    public class MachineSparePart
    {
        public int       MachineId   { get; set; }
        public Machine   Machine     { get; set; }
        public int       SparePartId { get; set; }
        public SparePart SparePart   { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how I configured the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MachineSparePart>(entity =>
{
    // Set the primary key
    entity.HasKey(e => new {  e.MachineId, e.SparePartId });

    entity
        .HasOne(msp => msp.SparePart)
        .WithMany(sp => sp.MachineMappings)
        .HasForeignKey(msp => msp.SparePartId);
    
    entity
        .HasOne(msp => msp.Machine)
        .WithMany(m => m.SparePartMappings)
        .HasForeignKey(msp => msp.MachineId);
});
```

The problem is this: if I include the mappings and then include the machine of the mapping entries, it causes an infinite loop.

```
var Data = _context.SpareParts
    .Include(et => et.MachineMappings)
    .ThenInclude(mm => mm.Machine)
    .AsQueryable();
```

Why? Other objects do work like this... I don't know...

Thanks for the help!

I tried commenting out the relationship definition in the `AppDbContext` and commenting out the collection inside the machine entity object. Then it worked. It also works when I remove the `ThenInclude machine`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by infinite loop? Is there a runtime error you are seeing? Then post the exact error test here. Is EF unable to map your model? Post the error for it. Also include definitions for the entities involved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this question before and the answer is the same. What's the *actual* problem or error message? EF doesn't loop. `data` is a *query* that hasn't been executed yet. It doesn't need `AsQueryable()` either, both `Include` and `ThenInclude` return an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for your answers. No there is no exception at runtime. It loads for a very long time and then it crashes with "Out of Memory" and exites with Code 0.

Comment: Are you getting a warning about cyclical references? This isn't looping at all. It tells you that your configuration results in an `A->B->A->...` cycle.  If I remember correctly the error message even tells you how to fix this by *not* using `HasOne` to say that the *Part* has a machine. After all, a machine has parts, not the other way around. if you let EF use conventions instead of explicitly specifying them, `Part` won't have a cyclical reference to `Machine`

Comment: @Julian, infinite loops are possible is such complex recursive LINQ translation library, so better create small reproducible sample and create issue in EF Core github repoistory. Also try `AsSplitQuery()` to ensure that you do not have Cartesian Explosion in Eager Loading.

Comment: @Julian add the actual code and *full exception text*, not just the type or message, in the question itself. What you posted is just an unexecuted query. Somehow, somewhere the application is calling `ToList` or `foreach` on that query. The full exception text includes the actual location that threw and a stack trace that shows which function calls led to the exception. This will show *what* really caused the crash - was it `ToList()`? Something else?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this isn't a recursive relation though, it's a straight many-to-many. `MachineSparePart` is the JOIN entity.

Comment: Which EF Core version is used? Have you checked the documentation on [Many-to-Many relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668197/ef-core-ends-in-infinite-loop)? In EF Core 7 there's no need to even have a JOIN class, it's generated automatically. Even if it's included, it shouldn't have any relation configuration. The relation is from `Machine` to `SpareParts`, the intermediate table is just the implementation of that relation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, again LINQ translation is not easy task, it is full of recursions and loops, and it is easy to fall into infinite loop in some corner cases. Eager Loading is definitely not straightforward algorithm.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv in this case though, it's just a matter of relation misconfiguration for a many-to-many relation. There's no LINQ code in the query at all so we don't know the *actual* query is.

Comment: Are you using something like `AutoMapper`, can you identify what part of the code is causing the infinite loop? The query generation part or the result materialization part? You can identify this using `dotnet trace`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the question's code that actively executes the query named `Data` or uses the results, so we can't guess what freezes. The relation is definitely wrong.

To fix the relation, remove the mapping of the join class  `MachineSparePart` entirely. The relation is a many-to-many from Machine to SparePart after all.

The [Many-to-Many relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) documentation shows that you don't even need a join type in EF Core 7. If your classes follow the naming conventions, EF Core will infer the join table from the actual entities themselves. You don't even have to explicitly specify the relation in the model.

You can [omit the join entity entirely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many) :

```
public class Machine
{
    public ICollection<SparePart> SpareParts {get;set;}
}

public class SparePart
{
    public ICollection<Machine> Machines{get;set;}
}
```

That's equivalent to the following code. Notice that only one direction is specified, from Machine to SparePart.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>()
        .HasMany(e => e.SpareParts)
        .WithMany(e => e.Machines);
}
```

If you really need to [use a join entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-navigations-to-and-from-join-entity), you only have to add `UsingEntity` to that single relation specification:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>()
        .HasMany(e => e.SpareParts)
        .WithMany(e => e.Machines)
        .UsingEntity<MachineSparePart>();
}
```

The [Many-to-Many Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) documentation explains how to handle multiple scenarios (16 right now), from [renaming the join table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-named-join-table) or [foreign keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-join-table-foreign-key-names), to [one-way relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#unidirectional-many-to-many), to having a [join type with extra payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-and-join-table-with-payload) (eg a date), to [self-referencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#symmetrical-self-referencing-many-to-many) scenarios, eg a `Person` class with a `List<Person> Friends` property.